# Connecting postgresql with asterisk using PGSQL()

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-connection, asterisk, ivr

I am trying to connect postgresql database with asterisk .For that I installed asterisk and postgresql.The [docs](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+PGSQL) says apart from odbc or realtime you can simply use `PGSQL()`.So when I do

```
exten => s,2,PGSQL(Connect connid host=localhost user=asterisk dbname=credit)
```

It gave me the error no application 'PGSQL' for that extension

Can anybody help me to connect asterisk with postgres .I dont want to use odbc and any agi or realtime.I had used MYSQL in my dialplan and it worked there as I read that MYSQL module is included default in asterisk so I can use it directly without ODBC as I am using .

How can I do same with postgresql in order to connect to it via asterisk?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation. The page that you linked says at the beginning:

> NOTE
>   This function is not available in asterisk. Either use ODBC or write this funtion.

Comment: but they also said `or write this funtion.` what does that means?

Comment: This is a not so funny way of saying: implement It yourself.